# Should I specify CAA records for www subdomain too?

Tags: dns, security-certificate

I pre-paid 5 years of AlpiroSSL Premium ([English info here](https://www.alpirossl.com/compare-ssl.html)), it's from Sectigo originally, but the certificate provider told me the right CAA is (or should be) `trust-provider.com` as per my current settings. I may switch to Let's Encrypt sometime in the future though, so I kept it there for hosting's sake. Anyway, my question is, if specifying CAA for both the domain and **`www` subdomain** makes sense?

```
0 issue "trust-provider.com"
0 issue "letsencrypt.org"
0 issuewild ";"
0 iodef "mailto:admin@vlastimilburian.cz"
```

---

### DNS CAA currently set

[image: DNS CAA currently set]

---

### SSL Labs showing CAA

[image: SSL Labs showing CAA]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Anyway, my question is, if specifying CAA for both the domain and www subdomain makes sense?

Not necessarily except if you really need that.
Why? Because `CAA` records cascade.

Per [RFC 8659](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8659) section 3, if a system has to find out a `CAA` record for `www.example.com`, it tries this name first, and if no response found, it continues "climbing up the root" and hence will try a `CAA` request on `example.com` (and theoretically later even on `com` and `.` in fact).

So, said differently, if you put a `CAA` record on `example.com` without any other records elsewhere in the zone, then that specific record will apply to all names in the zone.

Bases on your screenshot, you have the same `CAA` record on `www` and at apex, so the one at `www` is redundant but harmless.